# Autofac Log4Net integration

Tags: c#, .net, log4net, autofac

I was checking out the Log4NetIntegration contribution on the Autofac wiki (http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/Log4NetIntegration) and I'm having some trouble with the set up using version 2.4.

I really what to be able to achieve what the [follow up thread](http://groups.google.com/group/autofac/browse_thread/thread/41bf9d54f31b9dad/704f926779cbe8b3?#704f926779cbe8b3) is suggesting:

> "...register N services that all take a dependency on ILog, and have Autofac do the right thing supplying a logger instance for each type that declares the dependency."

There seem to be differences in how this happens in the new version. Specifically, IModule implements a different Configure method than the example in the thread.

```
public void Configure(IComponentRegistry componentRegistry) {}
```

as aposed to

```
public void Configure(IContainer container) {}
```

I'm new to Autofac so I'm not really sure where to go from here. Would appreciate any assistance.

Thanks,

Steve

Comment: The wiki example does exactly that - and is 2.4 compatible - can you please post some more details of how you're approaching this, or why cut and paste from the wiki isn't doing what you need? Cheers!

Comment: Hi Nicholas, you are correct. I'm not really sure why it wasn't working the first time round, but after spending some more time on it got the wiki example to work. What I'm not following though is the blog post - why the differnt implementation? Thanks for the follow up! Cheers, Steve